# The following problems occurred when installing crypto.jl in Julia

Tags: cryptography, julia

```
    (@v1.5) pkg> add https://github.com/danielsuo/Crypto.jl
    Cloning git-repo `https://github.com/danielsuo/Crypto.jl`
ERROR: failed to clone from https://github.com/danielsuo/Crypto.jl, error: GitError(Code:ERROR, Class:OS, failed to send request: 操作超时
)**strong text**
```

How to deal with this problem?

Comment: A side note, this package appears to be out of date. The last commit was made 5 years ago. You should use the SHA, Nettle, or ECC packages.

Comment: Opened an issues here: https://github.com/JuliaLang/Pkg.jl/issues/2528 I am guessing the outdating project structure is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like per here: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/error-could-not-find-project-file-in-package-at-https-github-com/44059 the package manager will not let you add packages that don't have a Project.toml file so I opened a PR to add a deprecation notice to Crypto.jl: https://github.com/danielsuo/Crypto.jl/pull/43

I opened an issue here: https://github.com/JuliaLang/Pkg.jl/issues/2528 and will request an updated error message for this issue.